# XMLSerializer is undefined in jest test

Tags: xml-parsing, jestjs, xmlserializer

I was using `XMLSerializer` class in one of NODE package class method. When writing unit test case using `jest` it threw error of `XMLSerializer is not undefined`. As this is native to browser, there can not be any package.

Even I searched online, found few suggestions of [using a new jsdom](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7537) and creating a prototype of XMLSerializer.

No proper solution is found even no posts at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently used a wrapped for `XMLSerializer` as below (typescript code):

```
export default class XmlSerializerWrapper {
    private serializer: XMLSerializer;
    constructor() {
        this.serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    }
    public serializeToString(doc: Document) {
        return this.serializer.serializeToString(doc);
    }
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: Could you please explain how and where you use this for the scenario described in the original question above? I am running into the same problem and am a bit stuck! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IanDevlin Sorry, I do not have the same code and context now. It was 2+ years back.

Comment: Yeah no worries, I know it was a long time ago, I was hoping, just in case. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today and came upon this post. My approach:

```
describe('MyXmlDocument', () => {

    global.XMLSerializer = function() {
        return {
            serializeToString : jest.fn(x => x) 
        };
    } 

    ... your tests here
});
```

My code only needs the serializeToString() method, so that's the only one mocked.